# Truncate string after certain index

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a string which I want to remove everything after a certain index (400).

Trim and TrimEnd do not help, as they only trim certain occurences and not everything.

```
If (exampleString.Length > 400) Then
    'truncate string after index 400
End If
```

Comment: if string length is less than 400 how can you remove everything after index 400??

Comment: Good point, edited it to be correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go with substring.
Then you will get string of length which you want.

Also you can trim it as it may contain suppose some empty space like if string is of length 600 but it may have empty space for example say 385-410 has empty space  & you are truncating at 400 so you will get 15 empty space so you can truncate it with trim() function to get out of useless empty spaces.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Mid

```
function Limit_String(Input as string,Limit as integer)
return Mid(Input,1,Limit)
end function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
newString = exampleString.Remove(400)
```